# Making UIToolbar Disappear

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

This is a pretty straightforward question, so I don't think I need to post code. I have an app in which a toolbar appears when a specific view is pushed by the navigation controller. However, when I go back to the previous view, the toolbar remains on the view. I've tried calling `[toolbar removeFromSuperview]`, as well as toggling UIToolbar's "hidden" property, within the view's `viewDidUnload` to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-(void)[UINavigationController setToolbarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated]`

Call that when appropriate.  `viewWillAppear:` is a good choice.  keep a flag as to what state you think it should be in

Comment: Thanks. Didn't work, unfortunately. I tried it it viewWillAppear as well. No luck. Any other thoughts? I added the toolbar with `[self.navigationController.view addSubview:toolbar];`.

Comment: If the toolbar is at the bottom of the screen, you should use the navigation controller's `toolbarHidden` property instead of creating your own toolbar. You can then either toggle this in `viewWillAppear:` or set the `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property of the view controller that should not show the toolbar.

Comment: Ah got it. That worked. Thanks! One more question though. Now it won't load my UIBarButtons... I'm calling    `[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:getDirections,flex,updateLocation,nil]];` and it's not showing any of them. Thoughts?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work with `self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:getDirections,flex,updateLocation,nil];` Thanks!